# Does @ComponentScan register discovered @Configuration classes to current application context automatically?

Tags: java, spring

In the code below, `AppConfig` is registered to application context, but `FooConfig` is not. And also `FooConfig` is not imported into `AppConfig`.
However, the application context can scan the `FooConfig`, and it will register `FooConfig` to the application context. And the beans defined in `FooConfig` can be discovered in current context.
Did I understand it correctly?
So `@Import` is optional if the imported config class is in the scan scope, right?

```
package app;
@Configuration
public class FooConfig { @Bean public Foo foo() { return new FooImpl(); } }

package app;
@Configuration
@ComponentScan("app")
public class AppConfig {  }

package app;
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        Foo f = (Foo) context.getBean("foo");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Because with that setting of `@ComponentScan` initialization will pick up everything from the `app` package, including `FooConfig`. Without it, you would need the explicit import.

Alternatively you could provide all config classes directly for the ApplicationContext constructor:

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class, FooConfig.class);
```